# Setting the value of a pointer by address through a message queue

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to declare a vector pointer, and then have it reference a vector found within an object. This is only complex because I must send it through a message queue system. The message queue only knows how to deal with ints, so the only thing I can pass it is an address cast to an int. When the message is processed, it must be converted back to a vector pointer, and then have its value set.

I have a miniature version of my problem here, that is failing in the same way. The "message queue" in this case is `GetItems` and the "message processor" is `GetItemsPrivate`

It is failing because the pointer value is still 0 after the process is complete, and even though I am getting a good address through the queue, I seem to be casting to the vector pointer incorrectly.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Box {
    public:
        std::string name;
        Box(std::string name);
        ~Box();
};
Box::Box(std::string name)
    :name(name)
{

}
Box::~Box(){}

class Item {
    public:
        std::string name;
        Box *box;
        Item(std::string name, Box *box);
        ~Item();
        void Print();
};
Item::Item(std::string name, Box *box)
:name(name),
 box(box)
{

}
Item::~Item(){}
void Item::Print(){
    std::cout << "Item name: " << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Item box: " << box->name << std::endl;
}

class Foo {
    private:
        void GetItemsPrivate(uint64_t item_ptr);
    public:
        std::vector<Item*> items;  
        Foo();
        ~Foo();
        void GetItems(std::vector<Item*> *&your_items);
};
Foo::Foo(){}
Foo::~Foo(){}
void Foo::GetItemsPrivate(uint64_t item_ptr){
    // pretend message receiver where ptr address is unpacked and then set 
    std::cout << "GetItemsPrivate param value 0x" << std::hex << item_ptr << std::endl;
    std::vector<Item*> *your_items = (std::vector<Item*> *)item_ptr;
    std::cout << "GetItemsPrivate ptr value " << your_items << std::endl; // should be 0 
    std::cout << "GetItemsPrivate ptr address " << &your_items << std::endl; // should be same address from main 
    // set the ptr to the map 
    your_items = &items;
}
void Foo::GetItems(std::vector<Item*> *&your_items){
    std::cout << "GetItems value " << your_items << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GetItems address " << &your_items << std::endl;
    // pretend message queue system where address must be shipped in a message
    GetItemsPrivate((uint64_t)&your_items);
}

void PrintItems(std::vector<Item*> *items){
    for(int i = 0; i < items->size(); i++){
        (*items)[i]->Print();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Box *boxA = new Box("BoxA");
    Item *itemA = new Item("Item A", boxA);

    Box *boxB = new Box("BoxB");
    Item *itemB = new Item("Item B", boxB);

    Foo foo;
    foo.items.push_back(itemA);
    foo.items.push_back(itemB);

    std::vector<Item*> *my_items = 0; 
    std::cout << "main value of my_items is " << my_items << std::endl;
    std::cout << "main address of my_items is " << &my_items << std::endl;

    foo.GetItems(my_items);
    // at this point, ptr should point to Foo's item vector
    std::cout << "main value of my_items is " << my_items << std::endl;

    //PrintItems(my_items);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

> main value of my_items is 0
>   main address of my_items is 0x7ffe61b0c2f8
>   GetItems value 0
>   GetItems address 0x7ffe61b0c2f8
>   GetItemsPrivate param value 0x7ffe61b0c2f8
>   GetItemsPrivate ptr value 0x7ffe61b0c2f8
>   GetItemsPrivate ptr address 0x7ffe61b0c288
>   main value of my_items is 0

Comment: `std::vector<Item*> *your_items` is a variable that is local to the function - it **cannot** have the same address as a variable in main

Comment: I know I can do this with a double ptr, I was just trying to do it the C++ way.

Comment: "The C++ way" would be to not do any of this weird pointer shenanigans and instead use a properly designed message queue that doesn't require casting pointers to integers (and leave out all the risks of *undefined behavior* that your code is running into)

Comment: Welp all I can use is this system, so, yeah. Double ptr it is.